# Automatic generate excel file with phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to automatically generate new excel file if i run this code:

```
    //file.php
    $arrtweet[] = array(....);

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("file/ABCDay-1.xlsx");

    $objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $objSheet->setTitle('Data ABC Day-1');
    $objSheet->getCell('A1')->setValue('User_ID');
    $objSheet->getCell('C1')->setValue('Content');
    $objSheet->getCell('D1')->setValue('Timestamp');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($arrtweet, NULL, 'A2');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,"Excel2007");        
    $objWriter->save("file/ABCDay-1.xlsx");
```

What I want is:

> PHP will automatically generate new excel file if I run that codes for day-2,day-3...,day-N

. Is that possible? Can you help me? thank you so much :')

Comment: You'll need to keep track of what day number you want, and maintain that in persistent storage like a filesystem file or a database, but it's perfectly possible. What's the problem?